# Installing Clint with Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, pip

I'm trying to install [Clint](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/clint/) (**C** ommand **L** ine **IN** terface **T** ools) in a Python 3.3 virtualenv.

Steps taken:

```
virtualenv -p python3 py3env
cd py3env
source bin/activate
pip install clint
```

The installation of Clint fails, due to a syntax error.

```
Downloading/unpacking clint
  Downloading clint-0.3.2.tar.gz
[…]
File "./clint/textui/prompt.py", line 33
    print prompt
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'm still quite a Python newbie, but I gather that the issue here is that `print()` is a function in Python 3 rather than a statement.

That being said, both the [Clint github page](https://github.com/kennethreitz/clint) as well as various other sources indicate that there is support for Python 3.2. Am I doing anything wrong here?

*Remarks:*

- I've been able to install other libraries such as Requests and docopt without any issue.
- The host environment is OS X Mavericks, though I doubt that matters.
- Pip installs the latest version of Clint (0.3.2).

If Clint doesn't support Python 3, is there an alternative library available with more or less the same feature set and support for Python 3?

Comment: If you don't mind downloading, building and installing Clint yourself, it's fairly straightforward to run `2to3 -w`, followed by `python setup.py install`.

Comment: For the record, it looks like `pip` doesn't run `2to3` before attempting to build Clint, and the Clint software itself does not support Python 2 and 3 with a single codebase. So support for Python 3.2 probably means, after you convert it with `2to3`.

Comment: Oh, at looking at its github pages: it's on the roadmap, so still to be done. Further, there is [this issue](https://github.com/kennethreitz/clint/pull/95) from a month ago with a fix that hasn't been pulled. Looks like its gone a bit silent (judging from the comments on that issue).

Comment: I also have the same problem in Windows wih Python 3.3

Comment: Thanks @Evert. Seems like this issue has already been fixed but is indeed waiting to be merged. I'm going to have to dive into Git and familiarise myself with it.

Comment: @Evert: if you can add your comment as an answer, I can flag this question as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the CLINT now fully supports Python 3. I was able to successfully install it using Python 3.4.